# Facebook App Token - does it ever expiry?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook App Token -

1. Do App Token ever expiry?
2. Do App Token ever change?
3. 1 Facebook app will only have 1 App Token, or can 1 Facebook App
   have multiple App Token?

Answer (score 2):

A Facebook application can only have one application token, resetting the secret changes it and invalidates the previous version.

A Facebook application can have multiple user access tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

> An App Access Token does not expire unless you refresh the application secret through your app settings.

Comment: Thanks alot  im just wondering, how come use an apptoken and not just use the client secret? what is the difference of having app token ?

Comment: @001 The point is that your app secret is never shared with anyone. Think of your app secret as the master password to your application. So giving an app token is the next secure big thing.

Comment: Make sense however is there a place where the app secret is used where the app token can not be used? if the app secret changes the app token changes.   if you give away your app token isn't it the same as giving away your client secret? trying to understand how an app token more secured than using the app secret.

Comment: @001 Read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#appsecret

Comment: it still makes no sense, what is the difference of you using a client secret and a app token? someone steals your client secret is the same thing as someone stealing your app token?

Comment: @001 Your app token is signed with your app secret. As explained in the link I just sent, stealing any results in your app being compromised